# Third triangle vertex in OpenGL is displayed at 0.0 when rendered in a window

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew, opengl-4

So I've been trying to learn OpenGL Lately with these videos (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2).

But when i tried to run the program using modern OpenGL instead of legacy OpenGL, i had a little problem that was, that the third position of my triangle was displayed at the "0, 0 position" instead of being displayed at the given position, "1.0, 1.0".

[image: image of window with modern OpenGL]

When I tried to write the code in legacy OpenGL the triangle was shown the correct way.

[image: image of window with legacy OpenGL]

Did I miss something in the vertex buffer, vertex attribute, vertex shader or fragment shader?

Below is the code I used with the legacy code 'faded away'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source) {
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result) {
        int lenght;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &lenght);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(lenght * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, lenght, &lenght, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "Vertex" : "Fragment") << "shader!:" << std::endl << message << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;

}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& VertexShader, const std::string& FragmentShader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    return program;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test schermpje", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "ERROR!!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    float positions[6] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,

    };

    unsigned int Buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &Buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, (const void*)8);

    std::string VertexShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 positions;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position = positions;\n"
        "}\n";
    std::string FragmentShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        ""
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
        ""
        "void main()\n"
        "{"
        "   color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(VertexShader, FragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shader);


    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /*glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glEnd();*/

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shader);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The offset of the 1st vertex coordinate is 0 rather than 8:

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, (const void*)8);`</s>

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, nullptr);
```

(If a named buffer object is bound then) the last argument of `glVertexAttribPointer` is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store. Since you've specified an offset of 8, the 1st vertex coordinate is stepped over.
When you set an offset of 8, then actually the 2nd, 3rd and 4th vertex coordinate is read form the buffer. Since the buffer has just 3 attributes, the last coordinate is by default (0.0, 0.0).

In your case it is even possible to pass 0 to the *stride* argument. This is a special case. If stride is 0, then Ithe generic vertex attributes are understood to be tightly packed and *stride* is computed by the tuple size and type.

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
```