# C++ OpenGL vertex position not changing from 0.0

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm a beginner in both C++ and OpenGl and trying to learn the latter with this series: https://thecherno.com/opengl. When trying to render a triangle the third vertex position displays at 0.0 and doesn't change, no matter what I change it to. The order of which set of floats renders which vertex is also different than in that YT series. Not an issue though.

```
float positions[6] = {
     0.8f, -0.8f,       // btm right corner
    -0.8f, -0.8f,       // btm left corner
     0.0f,  0.8f        // top center    <<---- ISSUE
};

unsigned int buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

[Top center vertex displays wrong location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKFk1.png)

I found the same problem here: [Third triangle vertex in OpenGL is displayed at 0.0 when rendered in a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61687594/third-triangle-vertex-in-opengl-is-displayed-at-0-0-when-rendered-in-a-window) but the answer is a different one, the person asking here is further along and uses a different/incorrect parameter.

I tried changing the third set of floats to different numbers `{..., 0.0, 1.0};` `{..., 0.5, 0.5};` `{..., 1.0, 1.0};` and tried changing some arguments, to no avail.

Comment: The vertices in your example have only 2 components (x, y), but not 3. So `glVertexAttribPointer(..., 2, ...)` instead of `glVertexAttribPointer(..., 3, ...)`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I misunderstood at first. Make this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd argument of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is the number of components per generic vertex attribute. The vertices in your example have only 2 components (x, y), but not 3

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);`</s>

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
```